# How to use Target Address for multiple rows in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel-formula, vba7

Need your guidance on how If i can apply Target Address & its Value for multiple rows.
I am new to VBA, The below code is working for 1 Row as of now, but how can i can apply for multiple rows.

Let's say, In a range from B4 to B10, if i select B7, then C7 & D7 should give " Please Select"
As of now its working for row B4 row only.

How it can be used for multiple rows.
Could you please guide me on this.

VB Code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$B$4" And Target.Value = "AA1" Then
Range("C4").Value = "Please Select"
Range("D4").Value = "Please Select"

ElseIf Target.Address = "$B$4" And Target.Value = "BB1" Then
Range("C4").Value = "Please Select"
Range("D4").Value = " "

ElseIf Target.Address = "$B$4" And Target.Value = "CC1" Then
Range("C4").Value = "Please Select"
Range("D4").Value = " "

ElseIf Target.Address = "$B$4" And Target.Value = "DD1" Then
Range("C4").Value = "Please Select"
Range("D4").Value = " "

ElseIf Target.Address = "$B$4" And Target.Value = "EE" Then
Range("C4").Value = "Please Select"
Range("D4").Value = " "

ElseIf Target.Address = "$B$4" And Target.Value = "" Then
Range("F4").Value = ""
Range("D4").Value = " "

End If
End Sub
```

[Target Address & Conditional Data Validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ayGR.png)

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that `Target` may be a multi-cell range - it's not guaranteed to be a single cell - so you need to allow for that possibility in your code.

`Select Case` would be useful here:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B4:B10"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'nothing to do...
    'loop over any affected cells in the range of interest
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        Select Case c.Value
            Case "AA1"
                c.EntireRow.Columns("C").Resize(0, 2).Value = Array("Please Select", "Please Select")
            Case "BB1", "CC1", "DD1", "EE"
                c.EntireRow.Columns("C").Resize(0, 2).Value = Array("Please Select", " ")
            Case ""
                c.EntireRow.Columns("C").Resize(0, 2).Value = Array("", " ")
        End Select
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Long
    If Target.Row > 3 And Target.Column = 2 Then
        r = Target.Row
        If Target.Value = "AA1" Then
            Range("C" & r).Value = "Please Select"
            Range("D" & r).Value = "Please Select"
        ElseIf Target.Value = "BB1" Then
            Range("C" & r).Value = "Please Select"
            Range("D" & r).Value = " "
        ElseIf Target.Value = "CC1" Then
            Range("C" & r).Value = "Please Select"
            Range("D" & r).Value = " "
        ElseIf Target.Value = "DD1" Then
            Range("C" & r).Value = "Please Select"
            Range("D" & r).Value = " "
        ElseIf Target.Value = "EE" Then
            Range("C" & r).Value = "Please Select"
            Range("D" & r).Value = " "
        ElseIf Target.Value = "" Then
            Range("F" & r).Value = ""
            Range("D" & r).Value = " "
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```